# Minimum number of vertex moves to un-intersect a polygon with itself

Tags: algorithms

In [my game](http://stndlkr200.github.io/21.html), I have `n` points that form a **self-intersecting polygon**. The points can be moved by dragging them. How can I form a **non-intersecting polygon** this way, in the minimum number of moves?

Comment: I thought of a solution for this but it's of exponential complexity. I suppose you could try it out because the problem itself does not seem to involve a large `N` so it might still be useful to you.

Comment: The gist of my deleted answer, for historical interest: I incorrectly equated the problem to a minimum deletion of vertices to simplify the polygon and proposed [a search](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XgsS6.png). Arthur pointed out [an example](http://i.stack.imgur.com/lWkOM.png) which it fails to solve optimally. ([Here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0802.1312.pdf)'s a link to a paper with a scientific treatment of the subject.)